# Solution of $\cos(z+w)=\cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the equation, $\cos(z+w) = \cos(z)$ for $z$. The answer is given as: if $w=2n\pi i$, then any complex number $z$ is a solution; else, there is no solution.

However, I am unable to see, how this answer can be obtained.

Comment: I think it should be $w=2n\pi$ instead of $w=2n\pi i$...

Comment: Also, for other $w$ there is still solution.

Comment: The correct claim is: "If $w=2\pi n$, then $\cos(z+w)=\cos z$." The converse of this, however, is false. (For instance, $\cos(z+\pi/3)=\cos(z)$ is true when $z=-\pi/6$ mod $2\pi$.

Comment: Are you sure there is $\cos$ in the question and not $\exp$?

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$$\cos \alpha = \cos \beta \iff \alpha = \color{red}{\pm} \beta +2k\pi \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$
So in your case:
$$\cos (z+w) = \cos z \iff z+w = \color{red}{\pm} z +2k\pi \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$
For the plus-sign:
$$ z+w = z +2k\pi \iff  w = 2k\pi \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$
So as long as $w = 2k\pi$, ***any*** $z$ is alright. But you also have the minus-sign:
$$ z+w = -z +2k\pi \iff  z = -\frac{w}{2} + k\pi \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$

Answer (score 0):

(i).... $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ for all complex $a,b.$

(ii).... $e^a\ne 0$ for all complex $a.$

(iii).... $\cos a= (e^{ia}+e^{-ia})/2$ and $\sin a=(e^{ia}-e^{ia})/2i$ for all complex a.

(iv). We show that any complex $a$ satisfies $\sin a=0$ iff $a/\pi \in \mathbb Z.$ The reason we need this will be clear, later. Let $a=c+id$ where $c,d$ are real numbers,and suppose  $\sin a=0.$ We have  $$\sin a=0\iff e^{ia}-e^{-ia}=0\iff e^{ia}(e^{ia}-e^{-ia})=0 \iff$$ $$\iff e^{2ia}-1=0\iff e^{-2d+2ic}=1\iff e^{-2d}(\cos 2c+i\sin 2c)=1\iff$$ $$\iff (e^{-2d}\cos 2c=1\land e^{-2d}\sin 2c=0)\iff (e^{-2d}\cos 2c=1\land \sin 2c=0).$$ Now $c$ is real so $\sin 2c=0$ iff $2c/\pi$ is an integer iff $\cos 2c=\pm 1.$ And $d$ is real so $e^{-2d}>0.$

So $1=e^{-2d}\cos 2c=\pm e^{-2d}\;$ iff $(d=0$ and $\cos 2c=1)$ iff $(d=0$ and $2c/\pi$ is an even integer) . So $\sin a=0 \iff a=c+id=c=n\pi$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z.$

Note: The reason $e^{-2d}(\cos 2c +i\sin 2c)=1\iff (e^{-2d}\cos 2c=1\land e^{-2d}\sin 2c=0)$ is that $e^{-2d}$ and $\cos 2c$ and $\sin 2c$ are real numbers.

(v)....The trig formulas $$(1)... \cos (a+b)= \cos a \cos b -\sin a \sin b$$   $$(2)... \cos (a-b)=\cos a \cos b+\sin a \sin b$$   are valid for all complex $a, b,$ which can be verified by entering the def'ns (iii) into the formulas.

Let  $M=(a+b)/2$ and $D=(a-b)/2.$ Then $$(3)...\cos a=\cos (M+D)=\cos M \cos D -\sin M \sin D$$    $$(4)... \cos b=\cos (M-D)=\cos M \cos D+\sin M \sin D.$$

Subtracting (4) from (3) we have  $$(5)... \cos a -\cos b=-2\sin M \sin D=-2\sin \frac {a+b}{2} \sin \frac {a-b}{2}.$$

So with $a=z+w$ and $b=z$ we have $M=(z+\frac {w}{2})$ and $D=\frac {w}{2}$. And $$ \cos (z+w)=\cos z\iff \sin M\sin D=0\iff$$ $$\iff (M/\pi\in \mathbb Z\;\lor \; D/\pi\in \mathbb Z)\iff$$ $$\iff [(z+w/2)/\pi\in \mathbb Z \;\lor \; (w/2)/\pi \in \mathbb Z)].$$